# share cookies between XMLHttpRequests and cordova plugin

Tags: android, web-services, cordova, cookies, intentservice

I'm struggling with *crosswalk* and *cordova plugin javacode* to let them share the same cookies.

**In javascript** an authentication cookie is created and updated during several `XMLHttpRequest`s to my *webservice*.

**In Java**, I have an `IntentService` which `onHandleIntent` gets called, for example when a location-update occures.
Inside of my `onHandleIntent` I want to call the same *webservice* as the javascript part mentioned above using the same cookies.
To retrieve the cookies I call `new XWalkCookieManager().getCookie(url)` and use it to make an HTTP-Call in Java including that cookie.

When the app is completly closed (via TaskManager), my `onHandleIntent` is still called. But I cannot call `getCookie(url)` since crosswalk is not running. `getCookie(url)` crashes uncatchable (ndk).

I already tried to cache the current cookie in my `MainActivity`s `onStop`, and it works on some device. But on other devices the app often gets closed without proper stop behaviour. So this is very fragile.

**So my question is**: Is there a way to either get crosswalks cookies when the app is closed or to intercept all requests done by javascript and cache the cookie to have the right one ready when the app is closed?

Comment: same crappy problem. did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since someone asks how I solved it, here is my heavy workaround, that contains 3 parts.

1. Every Request/Response
   My cordovaapp is using angular and I've put an $http-interceptor that intercepts EVERY response. Whenever a response is retrieved it calls my native plugin and calls an method "updateLocalCookie". In plugins Javacode, I put the actual cookies into a `SharedPreferences`-String.
2. Whenever a call from plugin/Java code is needed
   Get the current cookie from `SharedPreferences`, don't ask crosswalk to get cookie at all.
3. Whenever a response in plugin/Java code is retrieved
   This part is also very important. You normally also want to write back retrieved cookies to crosswalk. But `XWalkCookieManager.setCookies` is also not possible when app is in killed state.
   So I extended `MainActivity` (with cordova hooks after platform add) to contain a `BroadcastReciever` that writes back cookies to crosswalk.
   The response-callback will store the new cookies in `SharedPreferences` AND will send out a broadcast. If the app is running, the `BroadcastReciever` exists and writes the cookie. If the app is in killed, the `MainActivity` doesn't run so this broadcast will just be ignored.
   The last important part is, on every appstart the cookie also must be readed from `SharedPreferences` and write into crosswalk, because you missed those cookies during app-downtime.

Hope that helpes, feel free to ask/comment again if something is unclear since it is a very confusion workaround.